# Time Complexity of the Palindrome recursive algorithm

Tags: java, time-complexity, palindrome

What is the time complexity of the below code which checks whether the given input is palindrome or not?

```
public boolean isPalindromeRecursion(String input, int first, int last) {
    if (input.charAt(first) != input.charAt(last)) {
        return false;
    } else if (first >= last) {
        return true;
    }
    return isPalindromeRecursion(input, first + 1, last - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time complexity of your algorithm, is:

1. Strictly speaking - `O(n/2)`;
2. Speaking in the *Asymptotic Analysis* language - `O(n)`, as the [constant factors are disregarded](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2004fa/lectures/lecture16.htm) when we use Big O analysis, and [it's good](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/justification-for-neglecting-constant-factors-in-big-o) that they are disregarded.